# Control over index of Foor each loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I have tried this:

```
PHP:

<?PHP

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$query = "SELECT * FROM dress where dress_type='shirts' AND sex='male'";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {  { $path = $row["imagelocation"]; echo $path . "#";

    }

    mysql_close($link);

?>
```

as3:

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest("your_php_file.php") );

ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done); function _done(e:Event):void { ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);

var ar:Array = String(e.target.data).split("#");

for each(var i:String in ar)
{
    var img:Loader = new Loader();
    img.load(new URLRequest(i));

    addChild(img);
}

}
```

how to have control over the strings in the for each loop?

Answer (score 0):

if you want index too, why not use a regular for loop? it's easier that way, and faster both to code and execute

**Edit in response to first comment:**

```
for (var x:int=0; x<ar.length; x++)
{
    var i:String=ar[x];
    var img:Loader = new Loader();
    img.load(new URLRequest(i));

    addChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Actually i got the image path of images by php as a string. Now i have to show it in flash and also have to use as symbol. Than what shoul i do?

Comment: That way, you have the index in `var x:int`

Comment: Now how can i convert the ar[x] into symbol? i mean i have to use this images for avatar customization. So what should i do now?

Comment: How can i get the img width after loading the image?

Comment: instead of having a loader, you can use a `Image`. Then, set `img:Image=new Image()` and `img.source=i` if `img` is added to the screen and visible, you can get its width by img.width